# Airport Extreme firewall logging

Tags: network, airport, firewall, logs

I have a newer model (2013) Airport Extreme and have activated remote logging with level 7/debug messages going to a Linux box. However, I find the messages actually getting logged seem minimal, and I do not see anything from the firewall. I have even thrown nmap probes against it, and nothing gets logged.

I know logs can be viewed using Airport Utility 5.6, but I want to use a remote logger instead. Does anyone have a good case study of getting logs from an APE to a remote logger?

Are there keys in the plist I'm missing other than the entry for the remote logger's IP address and the log level?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to view logs in Airport Utility v6, or install 5.6 in Mountain Lion?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/57453/how-to-view-logs-in-airport-utility-v6-or-install-5-6-in-mountain-lion)

Comment: @bret7600 - I don't see how this is a dupe - the link you referenced is about how to view logs and this one is how to get more detail from the logs.

Comment: I agree that it is not a dupe. I'm looking specifically for more logging detail AND to have it sent to the remote logger. I will edit the question to make that clearer, and start a new question regarding the setting of the time zone.